# Disable auto drive scan in wine

Tags: linux, drivers, wine

I am using wine in Linux to run some Windows applications, but as mentioned [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_good_is_Wine_at_sandboxing_Windows_apps.3F), I want to remove as much as the drive settings in wine as possible so that the Windows applications cannot easily change my files in Linux. Each time I run `winecfg` and remove all drives except drive `C:` (first image below).

However, sometimes I have USB devices connected to Linux (say under `/mnt`), then sometimes when I open `winecfg`, it automatically detects the devices and map them into `D:` (second image below). How can I stop this behavior? I tried to make `~/.wine/dosdevices` unwritable, but this causes `winecfg` behave abnormally.

What I want:
[image: What I want]

What I get each time after opening `winecfg`:
[image: What I get]

Comment: It seems that a temporary workaround is to assign all drive number (`D:`, `E:`, ...) to a meaningless location

Comment: Cogpie suggested this question over on the Unix SE site should have the correct answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306297/how-to-stop-wine-from-assigning-drive-letters-to-mounted-devices-automatically/597038#597038

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is an answered duplicate on Unix SE site.

Answer (score 1):

i use a script to fill all drive letters and comx, run it in your prefix/dosdevices folder, winedevice doesn't create new drive letter if all are occupied and it will have dummy com ports if you don't want winedevice to populate dosdevices folder with com ports:

```
touch {a..z}{:,::}
mkdir -p com{1..40}
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked in the 'Unix & Linux' community and [I gave an answer you could find there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597038/421383)

Not sure if I should c/p it in here, or if there is a way to close as duplicate and link across communities. Please comment and I'll update. Thank you

Comment: As you don't have the Rep you cannot comment. We can post a comment with the link to the answer, and close this one.